# Textbox in powerpoint suddenly locked

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm working on a presentation in Powerpoint 2016. When I opened the document today, one of the text boxes is acting weird. I can't edit the text in it, or even change the size of the box. It worked fine yesterday, so I must have accidentally changed some settings. Other text boxes in the same document work as normal.

It seems as if the text box has magically transformed into a background picture, because:

1. If I right-click the weird textbox, I get the option "Format Picture" instead of "Format Shape".
2. If I select the text box, "Picture Tools Format" appears in the menu, and if I select that the "Remove Background"  button is clickable.

How can I get my text box back to normal? My google-skills couldn't solve this. Note: I'm pretty sure I haven't added the text box in Master View.

Comment: It seems that this text box is inserted as picture. As a workaround, I suggest you can copy this picture to OneNote, use Copy Text from Picture feature for this picture. Insert a new textbox in PowerPoint, paste the text in it. Save as this file to have a try.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Shape Format ->click on Send Backward. This will allow you to edit the text.